# Limit of division by zero problem.

Tags: calculus

Find the limit as $x\rightarrow0$ of $1/x$.

1) infinity.
2) 1. 3) 0. 4) The limit doesn't exist.

So I tried an experiment by plugging some values and I found that as I put small values, 1/that value get bigger and bigger, so the answer is infinity!

But one of my friends said that the correct answer is that the limit doesn't exist, what? How can he get that?

Comment: Here is a hint for you, draw the graph, online maybe using a graphing calculator like https://www.desmos.com. Next thing you do is to put some more reason into the notion of $x \to 0$. Ask yourself from which side does $x$ approach zero? See how your results differ?

Comment: There is no such thing as a division by $0$ problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember, a limit exists if the limit from the right is equal to the limit from the left. But that's doesn't hold for our limit since: $$\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}=\infty\quad\color{grey}{\text{and}}\quad\lim\limits_{x\to0^-}=-\infty.$$ You can see that by looking at the following plot:

$\phantom{XX}\,$[image: Plot made by your humble correspondent Hakim :-)]